# Optocoupler Package Markings

Tags: identification, opto-isolator, markings

I have a 4PIN dip octocoupler that’s cracked on the board of a power supply I’m fixing.

The markings on the optocoupler are
CT
817C
953K

What does the 953K mean? Is it a manufacturing batch number?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to CT817C datasheet from CT Micro:

- 9 = Fiscal Year
- 53 = Work Week
- K = Manufacturing Code